# Can't get any quests from Skyrim innkeepers except for Rising at Dawn

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I trying to find some quests to do, so I asked an innkeeper for rumors and I got Rising at Dawn. The trouble is, this is the quest that would cure my vampirism, and I don't want to do that. I figure that if I complete the quest anyways, I could still become a vampire again and then maybe I could get some new quests, but what if I get Rising Dawn again? I'd have to do it all over. Am I stuck with this, or have the innkeepers simply run out of quests for me?

Comment: Hmm, I waited three days and all of the innkeepers are giving the same quest.

Comment: Most of the inn keepers have one or other Quest for you..some shrot and some big and needs more than one location to visit.

Answer (score 2):

Innkeepers mostly give Radiant-generated generic quests, such as killing a giant or a bandit leader. Moreover, you don't need to complete a quest given by an innkeeper before getting another quest from an innkeeper. If you don't mind the Rising at Dawn quest sticking around your quest log, you can simply go to another innkeeper or revisit the innkeeper that gave you that quest after a few days to get more quests.